# Is there a way to use html5 custom elements without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

I know requiring javascript on a webpage has been a hot topic the last couple years.

I'm wondering if someone wanted to use [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) but still allow the website to be usable without javascript how would they do that?

Would they have to add a `<noscript>` with regular elements? or is there some way for browsers to know what to fall back to if a custom element is used but javascript isn't enabled?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to figure out what happens to your tags with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: I'm wondering what the best practice would be for someone who wants to use the new web components standard and still provide a usable experience for people who don't want to use javascript

Comment: The answer to most questions along the line “I want to do fancy stuff with JS but only as *progressive enhancement*” is “server-side rendering”.

Comment: is there a way to use server side rendering with web components?

Comment: This question should be asked at stackoverflow.com

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer is there a reason this should be asked at stack overflow.com instead of here?

Comment: @TonyBrix You are asking what code or technology you need to achieve an end goal, this is the domain of stackoverflow. This site deals with best practices and theoretical discussions in the profession of software engineering.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer I am not looking for specific code I am looking for a discussion on the best practices of using web components with a fallback for not requiring javascript. or if it is even possible at all.

Comment: @TonyBrix this is still off topic here. You are looking for advice about using a specific technology. The questions asked here should be, for the most part, language/technology agnostic

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer The top two tags on this site are "java" and "c#" I can almost guarantee none of those questions are language agnostic. Is there somewhere on this site that explains what a good/bad question for this site is?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, custom elements were not designed to be created with html-only syntax[1](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/).
They were created with the idea to change the DOM on the fly and add your own elements by javascript only.